# Passing data from jsp to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, pagination

I have an AJAX call that returns html, so I just call $("#my-div").html(data) in my javascript.

However, I am using twbsPagination which requires setting up the element through javascript.

The html element is defined as

```
<input type="hidden" name="totalPageCount" id="totalPageCount" value="${totalPageCount}"/>
<ul id="pagination" class="pagination-sm"></ul>
```

and the javascript is:

```
   callingFunction() {
     data = doAjaxCall().done(myFunction);
   }

  myFunction(data) {
     $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
            totalPages: $("#totalPageCount").val(),
            visiblePages: 5,
            onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                ...
            }
        });

     $("#my-div").html(data);
  }
```

Even though I have confirmed that the hidden field totalPageCount has the right value, $("#totalPageCount").val() returns the empty string. I'm guessing this is because it's looking for this element that only exists inside the html of data, not as part of what jquery is looking at.

What is the standard way to pass this kind of data?

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? When does the value for `totalPageCount` get set? Is it rendered server side in your JSP or set after your AJAX call returns? Also, when does `twbsPagination` get called? Immediately? Or, after your ajax call is made?

Comment: totalPageCount is set server-side during the AJAX call. I then made it client-side by putting it into a hidden input. It is "available" before my ajax call returns, but I have no idea how I'd use it from there. I don't know when twbsPagination is being called, but I originally had that JS in my document.ready,which seemed to work fine (it just doesn't meet this use case)

Comment: Is `doAjaxCall` an asynchronous call?

Comment: @JackPattishall Yes. Point taken. I fixed up the code to resolve that particular issue, but no change in this problem.

Comment: Have you tried swapping insertion of data (`$("#my-div").html(data);`) with the `twbsPagination` call?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this simply by switching around the order I executed the javascript.

```
 $("#my-div").html(data);

 $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: $("#totalPageCount").val(),
        visiblePages: 5,
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

By replacing the HTML first, jquery was able to find that element.

Comment: You nailed it. Still not sure this is the RIGHT way to do it though.

Comment: From experience, this is the fairly standard way of doing it! The only thing that might be of concern is IF multiple ajax calls are made (which calls `twbsPagination()` multiple times), does the `onPageClick` get bound multiple times? Would you need to perform any tear down?